# What are the advantages to using a graph database for a social network?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, nosql

I am looking at building a social network and was wondering the benefits of using a specific graph database (neo4j) compared to MySQL.

I am competent in using MySQL and was wondering if neo4j would offer anything more than ease of use. I am put off from using neo4j as I don't quite understand how to access it client side.

Please help

Comment: Basically you can query for patterns and perform depth-first queries more efficiently.

Comment: Graph databases excel when you want to do data-mining on the network. It makes it much easier and more performant to find people with common friends, people with similar interests or the degree of separation between people.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent resource is the *free* [Graph Databases](http://graphdatabases.com/) book from O'Reilly. It is written by folks at neo4j, and is chock full of information about why graph databases are better for social networking applications, and how to implement such applications.

Bottom line is: graph DBs can be several orders of magnitude faster than SQL DBs at social networking queries.

Comment: It's not free if I have to give them my information.

Answer (score 0):

Graph databases use to have a custom (like `Cypher` in case of `Neo4j`, `SPARQL` in case of `OrientDB`) or "standard" query language (like `Gremlin` in case of `TitanDB`, `OrientDB` or `Neo4j`).

These languages are oriented to perform complex queries (usually called traversals) like using patterns or navigation with multiple hops very efficiently.

For more details:

- Blueprints API: http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com/
- Gremlin language: http://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin